# Render lots of quads at once without stuttering

Tags: java, opengl

I have been trying to create a little platformer to learn more about OpenGL, but have found that when trying to draw loads of tiles/quads at once, the game stutters and freezes fairly regularly.

[image: Low frame rate is just in the gif]

Am using a tilemap for textures so only two `glBindTexture` calls per frame, but one `glDrawElements` per tile (hundreds per frame). This might be the issue but I cannot figure out how to do it any other way.

```
private void drawSprite(float xpos, float ypos, float scale, int index, SpriteSheet spriteSheet, boolean isPlayer) {
        Matrix4f view = new Matrix4f();
        view.lookAt(new Vector3f(positionX / 4.0f, positionY / 4.0f, 10.0f), new Vector3f(positionX / 4.0f, positionY / 4.0f, 0.0f), new Vector3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
        Matrix4f model = new Matrix4f();
        model.scale(scale, scale, 0.0f);
        model.translate(xpos, ypos, 0.0f);
        Window.shader.uploadMat4f("uView", view);
        Window.shader.uploadMat4f("uModel", model);
        Window.shader.upload2fv("offset", new Vector2f(spriteSheet.getXoffset(index), spriteSheet.getYoffset(index)));
        Window.shader.uploadFloat("columnCount", spriteSheet.getColumnCount());
        Window.shader.uploadFloat("rowCount", spriteSheet.getRowCount());
        if (looking == 1.0f || !isPlayer) {
            glBindVertexArray(Window.vao);
        } else if (looking == -1.0f && isPlayer) {
            glBindVertexArray(Window.vaoReflected);
        }
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    }
```

The above is the function that I call from update method once for every tile.

Comment: Obivous thing is that for each tile you recompute the same view matrix, reupload the same view matrix, rebind the same vertex array, recreate six new objects (I am not Java specialist, but I guess this is not a way to gain performance).
Considere drawing several tiles per draw calls using one (or more) vertex buffers that hold data for several tile at once. You could embed variables such as size, color, in the vertex buffers. This is especially true for background which is perfectly static.

Comment: 1) Use Instanced Rendering 2) Batch all quads with all their parameters together in a single VBO. Updating several uniforms per quad is definitely slower than updating a single VBO.

Comment: You can't think of a way to render 400 triangles except for rendering 2 triangles and then rendering another 2 triangles and then another 2 and then another 2 and ...?